# Intercept form POST string and send via AJAX instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is it possible to intercept a form's POST string and send it via AJAX instead? I could use $('form').submit() to intercept the POST event, but I don't see where I can get the POST string from. I could reproduce the string from the form's inputs, but this seems dubious.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
// capture submit
$('form').submit(function() {
     var $theForm = $(this);

     // send xhr request
     $.ajax({
         type: $theForm.attr('method'),
         url: $theForm.attr('action'),
         data: $theForm.serialize(),
         success: function(data) {
             console.log('Yay! Form sent.');
         }
     });

     // prevent submitting again
     return false;
});
```

Note that as [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188847/intercept-form-post-string-and-send-via-ajax-instead/12188859#comment16320417_12188859) stated in his comment that `.serialize()` doesn't include the submit button. If you also need to value of the submit buton you would have to add it manually.

Comment: Note that `serialize()` will not include the button clicked to submit the form. This may be important data to send, especially if the button  has a `name` attribute

Answer (score 3):

You can do of course - you prevent your form from submitting as usual, you take its data and perform a `POST` via jQuery:

```
$(form).submit(function(event){

    // prevents default behaviour, i.e. reloading the page
    event.preventDefault();

    $.post(

        $(this).attr('action'), // the form's action
        $(this).serializeArray(),   // the form data serialized
        function(data)
        {

            // what you are supposed to do with POST response from server

        }

    )

});
```

Comment: You probably want `serialize()`, not `serializeArray()` for use in `jQuery.post()`

Comment: `serializeArray()` always worked for me - I used it since `serialize()` left out textareas from urlencoded string, but that would have been a couple of jquerys ago, now `serialize()` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), it will ncode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

```
$('form').serialize()
```