# form is sending variables by get method

Tags: php, forms, validation, get

i got a form.

```
<form id="site-contact-form">
                    <div>
                      <div class="wrapper"><span>Ձեր անունը:</span>
                        <div class="bg">
                          <div>
                            <input type="text" class="input" name="contactname" id="contactname" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wrapper"><span>Ձեր E-mail-ը:</span>
                        <div class="bg">
                          <div>
                            <input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="textarea_box"><span>Տեկստ:</span>
                        <div class="bg">
                          <div>
                            <textarea  cols="1" rows="1" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                       <button id="sub" name="submit">ուղարկել</button>
                       </div>
                  </form>
```

As you see i got no action on it, no method. But when im clicking on button, its refreshing the page (like when it have action) and adding to URL ?contactname=&email=&message=&submit= ... I never met this problem before, why it is sending variables? I dont have any php on page yet...

Comment: its actually not refreshing the page, its sending you to new page with the Get parameters set

Comment: you should change your submit button to `<input type="submit" id="sub" value="ուղարկել" name="submit">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacause the default method is GET and the URL is the same of the page. Use:

```
<form method="POST" action="/reactor">
    <!-- .... -->
</form>
```

Actually, the `action` property is mandatory.

Comment: The thing is i dont want action (refresh of page), i'm planning to send the variables via ajax. What to do then?

Comment: That's fine. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188847/intercept-form-post-string-and-send-via-ajax-instead) explains how to catch submitted forms and send via AJAX using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the code with:

```
<form id="site-contact-form" method="post">
```

And the submitted values will not be displayed on the URL.

If you do not specify the form method, it will "get" by default.
This is happening here.

Answer (score -2):

Change the type of button as button

```
<button id="sub" name="submit" type="button">ուղարկել</button>
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: i added method="post" to my form, it still show the variables in URL and refresh the page

Comment: Thanks Manish Jangir, it helped!