# Not redirecting to another page after successful ajax request complete

Tags: php, ajax

I am validating a sign In form through ajax. After successful validation the form is not redirecting to the required page.

**Ajax Codes**

```
function login_submit(){
    var stat="";
    $("#submit").val("Loging in...");
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "php/login.php",
              data: {
                      uname: $("#uname").val(),
                      pass : $("#pass").val()
                    },
              success: function(result) {
                          if(result=="parent"){
                              window.location = "http://localhost:90/auction/augeo/admin/parent_admin/index";
                          }
                          else if(result == "sucess_normal"){
                              window.location.assign("../normal_admin");
                            }
                          else if(result == "deactivated account") {
                              window.location.assign("reactivate_account/");
                            }
                          else if(result == "banned account") {
                              window.location.assign("banned_account/");
                          }
                          else{

                            $("#submit").val("Login");
                            $("#error_msg").css({color: 'red'});
                             document.getElementById("error_msg").innerHTML= result;
                             stat = false;


                      }
                    }
               });
    if(!stat)
      return false;
  }
```

**The php code**

```
if(isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
    $username = encode($_POST['uname']);
    $password = encrypt(encode($_POST['pass']));

    // check if entered username and password is in the database
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * From admin_account where admin_account.username = '$username' AND admin_account.password = '$password' ");
    if($row = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        $found = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if($found['state'] == 1){
            $account_id = $found['account_id'];
            setcookie("admin_id", $account_id, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
            $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $account_id;


            $result1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT role_id From admin where admin_id = '$account_id'");
            $found1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
            $_SESSION['account_type'] = $found1['role_id'];
            if($found1['role_id'] == "1"){
                echo "parent";
           //header("Location: http://localhost:90/auction/augeo/admin/parent_admin/index");
            }else{
                echo "sucess_normal";
            }
        }
        elseif($found['state'] == 2){
            echo "banned account";
        }
        else{
            $_SESSION['deactivated_id'] = $found['account_id'];
            echo "deactivated account";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
    }
}
```

I have tried all I could do but to no avail. I want to check if **result=="parent"** and if **result=="parent"** it should redirect to  **window.location = "http://localhost:90/auction/augeo/admin/parent_admin/index";** but instead it is echoing out **parent**.

Comment: What is the output if you alert the result ? What if you remove the last if(!stat) becuase it will be rendered before ajax return a response or you must set async property to ajax to false if you want that it will be rendered after ajax request finishes

Comment: Try also to use document.location.href instead of window.location.Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You say "it is echoing out parent". **But this should never happen with the AJAX code you supplied**.

So I'm suspecting that you have a form that's running its own default submit, and *that* is what you're seeing.

You may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188859/1428679):

```
$('#idOfYourForm').submit(function() {
     var $theForm = $(this);

     // This is a button or field, right? NOT the form.
     $("#submit").val("Logging in...");

     $.post(
          'php/login.php',
          {
                  uname: $("#uname").val(),
                  pass : $("#pass").val()
          }
     ).done(function(result) {
          // check the result
          alert("Server said: " + result);
     });

     // prevent submitting again
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the button with

```
$("#submit")
```

This is ok, but if the button is defined as:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="..." />
```

You'll get a subsequent submit of the form the button is defined in.

To avoid this, a far easier solution to the other suggested, is to not use a submit button at all. Instead, use a simple action button. These are two examples, the second of which is probably better because it is easier to design with bootstrap/HTML5/CSS...

```
<input type="button" id="submit" value="..." />
```

or better:

```
<button type="button" id="submit">...</button>
```

In case of slow server/network, you'll probably want to aid AJAX usability by disabling the button:

```
$("#submit").val("Logging in...").prop("disable", "disable");
```

This helps avoiding multiple submits when the server is slow and the user impatient.