# How to implement js to django to run 3 functions?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-views

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188847/intercept-form-post-string-and-send-via-ajax-instead) which could work for me, but I don't know javascript. I want to run 3 functions like you see in my views.py, but I'm unable to do that because I use `(forms.Form)` one document that is uploaded to run 3 functions. Can you help me implement this js code to my django site.

This is forms.py

```py
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

This is views.py

```py
def save_exls(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            return redirect('html_exls')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    context = {'documents': documents, 'form': form,}
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)


def pandas_exls(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            output = io.BytesIO()
            newdoc = request.FILES['docfile']
            dfs = pd.read_excel(newdoc, sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)
            for name, df in dfs.items():
                #pandas stuff
                done.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)
            output.seek(0)
            response = HttpResponse(
                output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
            return response
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'form': form})


def html_exls(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            output = io.BytesIO()
            newdoc = request.FILES['docfile']
            dfs = pd.read_excel(newdoc, sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)
            for name, df in dfs.items():
                #pandas stuff for html 
                done.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)

            html = done.to_html()
            print(html)
            output.seek(0)
            response = HttpResponse(
             output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
            return response
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'form': form})
```

This is html file, list.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Django site</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url "pandas_exls" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>

            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
        </form>
        <br/>
            {{html|safe}}
        

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

See comments to make sense of this edit. This is what I tried before, to put everything in one function but it did not work.

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            output = io.BytesIO()

            newdoc = request.FILES['docfile']
            #newdoc.save()  * if I include this, I got an error, see below

            dfs = pd.read_excel(newdoc, sheet_name=None, index_col=[0])
            writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output)
            for name, df in dfs.items():
                df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
                new_data = df.stack(0)
                #rest of pandas computation everyting until done
                done.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=name)

            html = done.to_html()
            writer.save()
            output.seek(0)
            # return render(request, 'list.html', {'table': html}) **can't render html and it will not be showed
            filename = f"calculated_{newdoc.name}"
            response = HttpResponse(
                output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
            return response
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'form': form})
```

'*' I got this error, `AttributeError at /uploadfile/ 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'save'`

'**' Can't have two `return`s

Comment: Hey there, from you code exemple, I see that you are calling the function `pndas_exls`. And from what I understand from your question you would like to run `save_exls` and `html_exls` but all those function returns to the user something different. Could you go a bit into detail as to what should happend ? To the user

Comment: @Paulo User needs to upload (excel) file. After that I need to save that document on server (this is not important for user) after that pandas_exls will do some pandas calculations and pop up download window for user... and additionally will show some tables in html page. Because I cannot make in one function to work everything I got three functions: 1 - just needs to save file; 2 - needs to do pandas calculations and download file, and; 3 -  needs to do again calculations and show tables in html page (I know that it does twice pandas calculations but doesn't know other way ).

Comment: Then I think you it is not necessary to have 3 endpoint for that. As you use the same file. It would be more efficient to have it sent only once. Furthermore I believe pandas computation are quick (a few millisecond ?). If so what I would do is, in the same end point do all 3 things, 1) first save the file, 2) perform the computation with panda and save it as another file. 3) return the table of data computed by panda, and add a link to the file you generate previously so that the user can also download it. In the end only one endpoint is necessary performing all 3 tasks.

Comment: Does this make sense for you ? Are they some pitfalls I did not anticipate?

Comment: I have tried to do that, I edited my answer. I got an errors, maybe you can solve them. Note: pandas time depends, some bigger documents it can take even 10 seconds. See edited part, you will see everything in one function.

Answer (score 0):

forms.py

```
from django import forms    
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from calculation import handle_uploaded_file


def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            html_to_show = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponse(html_to_show)
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

calculation.py

```
def do_calculation(fname):
    df = pd.read_excel(fname)
    #Perform df operations here
    return df.to_html()

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    fname = 'some/file/name.xlsx'
    with open(fname, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    return do_calculation(fname)
```

## EDIT (how to serve uploaded files)

We will render a another view which is expecting 2 variables from response `file_url` & `html_table_to_show`

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from calculation import handle_uploaded_file


def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            html_to_show, file_url = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return render(request, '/viewToRender.html', {
        'uploaded_file_url': file_url, 'table_view': html_to_show 
    })
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

calculation.py

```
def do_calculation(fname):
    df = pd.read_excel(fname)
    #Perform df operations here
    df.to_excel(fname)
    return df.to_html()

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    fname = 'some/file/name.xlsx'
    with open(fname, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
    return do_calculation(fname), fname
```

Comment: Let me provide a link  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/.   You can read it out from here.

Comment: At calculation.py `fname = 'some/file/name.xlsx'`, in what i need change some/file/name.xlsx?

Comment: Basically it is the name of file you want to store. It can be same as users or you can replace it with yours.

Comment: `UploadFileForm` is not created. Is it `DocumentForm` instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237620/discussion-between-project-py-and-danish-bansal).

Comment: It's the name of function in forms.py

Comment: Yes for DocumentForm, not UploadFileForm. Aside from this, 
I got this (django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'file') at html_to_show, file_url = handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])